# Копирование текста из div в meta

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Добрый вечер.
В общем мне нужно скопировать текст из `<div>` в `<meta name="description" content="">` при помощи JQ.
Как реализовать?
Желательно с кодом и пояснением.

Comment: + ограничить текст на определённое кол-во символов.

Comment: ??? мета - это заголовки. JS - это внутри. Вопрос кажется неопределенным.... Ведь после отсылки заголовков их менять не получится...

Comment: @DNS, мета-теги и заголовки http запроса, мягко говоря - разные сущности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё просто, вот пример:

```js
var text = $('.text-item').text(); //Выбираем текст из div
text = text.slice(0,10); //обрезаем текст с начала и длиной 10 символов
$('meta[name=description]').attr('content', text) // вставляем в attr content  текст
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="description" content="">
<div class="text-item">Задача организации, в особенности же постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности играет важную роль в формировании модели развития. Таким образом постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности позволяет оценить значение системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Ну и ванильный вариант.

```js
const meta = document.querySelector('meta[name=description]');
const text = document.querySelector('#div').textContent;

console.log(meta.getAttribute('content')); // !!!

meta.setAttribute('content', text.slice(0, 20));
console.log(meta.getAttribute('content')); // Lorem ipsum dolor si
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="!!!">
</head>
<body>
<div id="div">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore rem, doloremque et, inventore ipsam tenetur impedit, accusantium aliquid libero fugiat error voluptas dolor enim, laborum accusamus doloribus quam. Distinctio, sed.</div>
</body>
</html>
```